# Two ManyToMany fields without backwards relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to have a model with 2 ManyToMany fields without allowing a backwards relation.
So here is the model:

```
class Camp(models.Model):
#...

free_options = models.ManyToManyField('Option', related_name='+')
paid_options = models.ManyToManyField('Option', related_name='+')
```

After trying to do

> python manage.py syncdb

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: One or more models did not validate: camps.camp: Accessor for
>   m2m field 'free_options' clashes with related m2m field  'Option.+'.
>   Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'free_options'.
>   camps.camp: Reverse query name for m2m field 'free_options' clashes
>   with related  m2m field 'Option.+'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'free_o ptions'.

Is it not possible to have 2 fields without backwards relation on the same model? how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if that would help but try [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Comment: I've changed my related_name values to 'camp_free_options' and 'camp_paid_options', so i'm not going to use backwards relations. But if you have any solution for that, so i will be able to use backwards relations, please tell us.

Comment: @aisbaa I didn't understand the difference between the related_name and through.

Comment: With `through` option you have to create model which is responsible for relation between camp and options. BTW what you described feels like a bug in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ask why you're bothered by having the backwards relation, just don't use it if you don't want it.  But to answer the question, no there isn't a way to remove it entirely.

Comment: Alright thanks. This is what i did. I also mentioned related_name values because i have 2 ManyToMany fields as i mentioned above.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) state that you can remove backward relation, maybe django team cheated a bit.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django documentation for the [related_name argument of the ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name):

> If you have more than one ManyToManyField pointing to the same model
>   and want to suppress the backwards relations, set each related_name to
>   a **unique** value ending with '+'

Emphasis mine.

So if you want to do that, you should be able to simply:

```
class Camp(models.Model):
    #...

    free_options = models.ManyToManyField('Option', related_name='free_options+')
    paid_options = models.ManyToManyField('Option', related_name='paid_options+')
    #                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to suppress the backwards relation on multiple ManyToManyField's in the same model.

Hope this helps!